# Excel get value from vertical cell sheet reference to horizontally cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Sheet 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zTat.png)
[Sheet 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHt55.png)

I have two sheet with different cell orientation, one is vertical and one is horizontal

I want to fill horizontal cell in sheet 6 based on reference value from sheet 5 which is vertical cell.

I want create formula "IF date 1 on sheet 6 is IN then get value from date 1 IN on sheet 5"

I already use some IF statement but when I drag it to right, the formula reference on sheet 5 also moved to right. Can it changed to move down?

Comment: Are column A cells formatted as Date? Or Custom? Or is it General,? Or Text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the issue correclty, you can use the `indirect` function to construct the cell pattern.

For example, if you write `=INDIRECT("Sheet5!B"&COLUMN(A1))` on the Sheet6 cell and then drag it to the right it will move the reference down on the Sheet5.

You can combine your existing conditions with that function to achieve the result.

Comment: It's almost work, but I don't understand what is COLUMN(A1) mean, could you explain for me?

Comment: Sure! Basically, it gets the column number of a cell. So, COLUMN(A1) is 1 because "A" is the first column. When you drag it to the right, it becomes COLUMN(B1) and it equals 2 (because "B" is the second column). Next you feed it into the INDIRECT function as a row part of a cell address

Comment: thank you, i modified and applying your answer and it's work.